# Heap variable scope

Tags: c++, templates, variables, scope, syntax-error

I am implementing a heap and I'm having trouble understanding why the variable 'int hole' isn't in scope in my insert method. I've tried many things for example, declaring it in the method as well as in the class. The for loop in my insert is what's throwing the error.

```
template <class Comparable>
class BinaryHeap
{
    public:
        explicit BinaryHeap( int capacity = 100 );
        bool isEmpty( ) const;
        bool isFull( ) const;
        const Comparable & findMin( ) const;
        void insert( const Comparable & x );
        void deleteMin( );
        void deleteMin( Comparable & minItem );
        void makeEmpty( );
    private:
        int currentSize; // Number of elements in heap
        vector<Comparable> array; // The heap array
        void buildHeap( );
        void percolateDown( int hole );
 };

template <class Comparable>
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::insert( const Comparable & x )
{
    if( isFull( ) ) //throw Overflow( );
    // Percolate up
        int hole = ++currentSize;
    **for( ; hole > 1 && x < array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2 )**
        array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
        array[ hole ] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `throw` commented out, the `if` statement looks like

```
if( isFull( ) )
{
    int hole = ++currentSize;
}
```

The variable `hole` is only "in scope" inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I'm working on the overflow later. That makes sense and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Without curly braces (`{}`), `if` and `for` blocks contain only a single statement. So if we add them for clarity, you're code would in fact be equivalent to the following:

```
if( isFull( ) ) {
    int hole = ++currentSize;
}
for( ; hole > 1 && x < array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2 ) {
    array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
}
array[ hole ] = x;
```

When written like this, it's obvious why the code does not compile. Instead, you should ad the curly braces yourself so they properly represent the blocks you intended to have:

```
if (isFull()) {
    int hole = ++currentSize;
    for (; hole > 1 && x < array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2) {
        array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
        array[ hole ] = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `array[ hole ] = x;` is outside the `for`-loop.
2. `hole` is declared only inside the body of `if( isFull( ) )`.

It should probably look more like this:

```
int hole = /* initial value */;

if( isFull( ) )
{
    //throw Overflow( );
    // Percolate up
    hole = ++currentSize;
}

for( ; hole > 1 && x < array[ hole / 2 ]; hole /= 2 )
{
    array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
    array[ hole ] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the variable hole is declared inside the "then" branch of the if clause. You may be missing some curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Where you wrote

```
if( isFull( ) ) //throw Overflow( );
```

I think your intent was

```
if( isFull( ) ) {
 //throw Overflow( );
}
```

Others explained what happens to the following line when it gets associated with that `if` because you left out those `{ }`

BTW, I notice you are using 1 based indexing.  Most documentation of heap algorithms assumes 1 based indexing, so I expect that is why.  But std::vector uses 0 based indexing.  If your intent is to waste element 0 of the vector, remember that when resizing the vector to `capacity+1` rather than just `capacity`.  When I code heap algorithms, I always redefine the rules for 0 based indexing.  Instead of `H[i]<=H[2*i] && h[i]<=h[2*i+1]` I use the rule `H[i]<=H[2*i+1] && h[i]<=h[2*i+2]`